# Possible to attach Node's built-in profiler to an existing process

Tags: node.js, profile

I'm familiar with Node's build in CPU profiler:

`NODE_ENV=production node --prof server.js`

... but can the profiler be attached to a running process.

The problem I need to solve is that there is a lot of heavy lifting during start up on our IoT Gateway and I want to profile the CPU only AFTER the heavy lifting during steady state, so I want to attach it to the running process rather than monitor from start up as it will totally mis-represent my steady-state.

I am aware you can do this with the debugger, but I need to do it for the profiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use remote inspector

```
 NODE_ENV=production node --inspect-brk server.js
```

Now, go in chrome to `chrome://inspect` and launch NodeJS Inspector and resume the application

1. Manually start the profiler from `Profiler` tab.
2. You can start profiler within your code with `console.profile()` and `console.profileEnd()`

---

If you want to inspect remote server:

1. Start the script with: `NODE_ENV=production node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 server.js`
2. In `chrome://inspect` click `Configure` new `Discover network targets` and add the IP address and `9229` port of your server. Refersh the page, and then you will see your remote server to inspect.

Make sure to open the `9229` port on remote server firewall. If you can access only `22`(ssh) then try to open ssh-tunel: `ssh -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 some@myserver -N`. *Then you can start the server only with `--inspect` flag, without ip-binding.*

Comment: That's a great tip thank you ... but in this case the device running Node that I need to monitor is remote and behind firewalls that I can't get to. I can only see a way to do it through SSH

Comment: Yeah that's great, I will tunnel through ssh to the server and attach the debugger through the browser, then profile from there. That'll work great, thanks a bunch!